# Change node title and node field content

Tags: 7, nodes

I try to change the values of the title and a field of a node.

```
function module_node_view($node, $view_mode, $langcode) {
  $node->title = 'TEST';
  $node->field_description[$node->language][0]['value'] = 'CONTENT';
}
```

When I try this, nothing is changed...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to change the node title, or the content of a field, you should implement [hook_node_presave()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_presave/7), which is invoked when a node is created, or updated; [hook_node_update()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_update/7), which is invoked when a node is updated; [hook_node_insert()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_insert/7), which is invoked when a node is created.
If you implement `hook_node_presave()`, you don't implement the other two hooks.

The purpose of [hook_node_view()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_view/7) is changing `$node->content`, which is used to build the view of the node.

The hook is called from [node_build_content()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.module/function/node_build_content/7), which is called from [node_view()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.module/function/node_view/7). This function contains the following code.

```
  // Populate $node->content with a render() array.
  node_build_content($node, $view_mode, $langcode);

  $build = $node->content;
  // We don't need duplicate rendering info in node->content.
  unset($node->content);

  $build += array(
    '#theme' => 'node', 
    '#node' => $node, 
    '#view_mode' => $view_mode, 
    '#language' => $langcode,
  );

  // Add contextual links for this node, except when the node is already being
  // displayed on its own page. Modules may alter this behavior (for example,
  // to restrict contextual links to certain view modes) by implementing
  // hook_node_view_alter().
  if (!empty($node->nid) && !($view_mode == 'full' && node_is_page($node))) {
    $build['#contextual_links']['node'] = array('node', array($node->nid));
  }

  // Allow modules to modify the structured node.
  $type = 'node';
  drupal_alter(array('node_view', 'entity_view'), $build, $type);

  return $build;
```

If you need to change the output of a field, or the part of a node view that shows the node title, you need to change `$node->content` in `hook_node_view()`.

As example, this is the content of `$node->content` for a taxonomy reference field. For other fields, the array can have a different structure.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Could you give one advice? What hook is better to use is node layout is made with Display Suite and I want to alter layout only in one field?

Answer (score 1):

I think the $node will be a object and not array. You are trying to access it like an array, hence you get php error.

```
function module_node_view($node, $view_mode, $langcode) {
  $node->title = 'TEST';
  $node->field_description[$node->language][0]['value'] = 'CONTENT';
}
```

Comment: Stupid mistake indeed :) The white screen is gone, but the page shows the original content. I think I'm doing this in the wrong hook?!

Comment: Dinesh we can't modify node like this in hook_node_view